# Plotting a 2-D (of 4D data) contour in matplotlib using numpy arrays

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, contour

I basically have a potential 'V' that depends on three coordinates - x,y and z. The objective is to plot a 2-D contour image of the potential for varying x and y (that is, for a fixed z). This is how I attempted to do it: 1) Import the data of x,y,z,V and store it separately. 2) Create a grid data of coordinates using 'meshgrid'. 3) Plot the contour for a fixed 'z'.

I don't seem to have an issue with the first two parts, but I suspect I don't quite know the syntax for part 3. Here is the code from my attempt:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

filename = 'x.txt'
data=np.loadtxt(filename)
x = np.loadtxt(filename,usecols=0)
filename = 'y.txt'
data=np.loadtxt(filename)
y = np.loadtxt(filename,usecols=0)
filename = 'z.txt'
data=np.loadtxt(filename)
z = np.loadtxt(filename,usecols=0)
X,Y,Z = np.meshgrid(x,y,z)
filename = 'V.txt'
data=np.loadtxt(filename)
v = np.loadtxt(filename)
v = v.reshape(len(x),len(y),len(z))

plot.contour
```

The last line is incomplete because I havent quite figured out how to specify a fixed 'z' value and plot the 2D contour. I believe the upper portion of the code does the job I outlined earlier, but I might be wrong with this as well. I would appreciate any help with this problem. To restate the problem, basically I have data of x,y,z and V (which depends on all 3 coordinates) and I intend to plot a 2-D contour of V for a fixed 'z' value.

Comment: You just need `X0, Y0 = meshgrid(x, y)` since you're doing that slice, and then take a `V0` section that corresponds to the Z that you're interested in, and then `contour(X0, Y0, V0)`.

Comment: `plt.contour(x, y, v[:, :, index])` is what you want.  You may want to be sure that your `v.reshape` was the right way around as well.

Comment: @JodyKlymak interesting. The first part makes sense, and simplifies things a lot. Can you expound a little bit on the second part? Doesn't reshape here work as expected? (that is, it just has the dimensions x * y * z)?

Comment: sure, reshape works as expected, but data can be stored in different orders.  i.e. V[nz, ny, nx] is also often used...